# Amazon web services and tensorflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

As someone who has a laptop with insufficient processing power, I am having a hard time trying to train my neural network models. So, I thought of Amazon Web Services as a solution. But I have a few questions. First of all, as far as I know, Amazon SageMaker supports TensorFlow. I could not understand if the service is free or not though. I have heard some people say that it is free for a specific time, others say that it is free unless you surpass a limit. I would be more than happy if someone could clarify or put forward other alternatives that would help me out.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google cloud has similar options and they give $300 credit to developers. 
Since google is the creator of tensorflow, I am guessing their cloud would be the one most up to date the latest. Try it out.

https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/pricing

Answer (score 1):

They have a free tier, and this is all well documented at https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/pricing/

Answer (score 1):

You should look into EC2 Spot Instances.

There is a market for AWS computing resources with prices rising and falling with supply and demand. You can set a max price as long as you are flexible on the availability. When the prices fall (usually at night), you can take advantage of (big data) computing resources at 90% off.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/how-spot-instances-work.html